# Why does the table does not display in html?

Tags: css, html

i wrote a html code. here i created a form inside which some rows are to be display and a table. Everything is fine but the table does not display in the browser. can you please help me. thanks in advance.

the code is:

```
<form>
<div id="formWrap">
<h1 align="center" style="color:#0000FF" >B.E. Degree Course Registration</h1>
<div id="form">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="label0" style="color:#FF0000; font-style:italic; margin-left:20px; font-size:18px">Personel details:</div>        
    </div> <!-- end of 0th row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Name</div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" id="fullname" required="required" class="detail" name="fullname" />
        </div>
        <div class="label">Sex</div>
      <div class="inputradio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio" required="required" class="detailradio" name="sex" />
        <span class="style7">Male</span>
        <input type="radio" id="sex" required="required" class="detailradio" name="sex" />
        <span class="style7">Female </span></div>
    </div> <!-- end of first row -->
<div class="label3">ECA</div>
        <div class="inputeca">
            <select name="eca">
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="eca1">NSS</option>
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="eca2">NCC</option>
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="eca3">Cultural</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="label3">Year</div>
        <div class="inputyear">
            <script language="JavaScript"> <!-- start JS code hide
                // loop to create the list
                var year = 2012
                document.write("<select name='years'>");
                for (var i=1; i <=200; i++)
                {
                    year++;
                    document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
                }
                // end JS code hide -->
            </script>
            <p></p>
        </div>              
    </div> <!-- end of row -->  
    <table width="600" border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
    <td>col5</td>
   <td>col6</td>
  </tr>       
</table>
<div class="row">       
<div class="submit" style="margin-left:708px">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Proceed"/>
</div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>  
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you need `document.write("</select>");` somewhere?

Comment: Also, `<!--` is not a comment in Javascript. Use `// single-line comment` or `/* multi-line comment */`

Comment: @trojansdestroy he has // in front of the html comment. its intended for super old browsers, useless but it is in fact done the right way

Comment: @user1721135 I mean the line where he opens the script block. Wouldn't `<!-- some text` in a script block be interpreted as plain text? **EDIT:** Not at all, just looked it up. Useful for hiding JS from older browsers? Interesting. Thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: You might be interested in the *number* input element instead:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/yzsnurxd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> <!-- start JS code hide
// loop to create the list
        var year = 2012
        document.write("<select name='years'>");
        for (var i=1; i <=200; i++)
        {
            year++;
            document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
        }
        // end JS code hide -->
</script>
```

To

```
<select name="years">
<script language="JavaScript">
     // loop to create the list
     var year = 2012
     for (var i=1; i <=200; i++)
     {
         year++;
         document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
     }
     // end JS code hide -->
</script>
</select>
```

You don't need to start the `select` tag with JS, and you forgot to close the tag so the table wouldn't show (as well as other stuff, probably).

Answer (score 0):

Your script is just not closing the select element so the table was inside the select.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> <!-- start JS code hide
            // loop to create the list
            var year = 2012
            document.write("<select name='years'>");
            for (var i=1; i <=200; i++)
            {
                year++;
                document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
            }
            document.write("</select>")
            // end JS code hide -->
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the select tag

```
       <script language="JavaScript"> <!-- start JS code hide
            // loop to create the list
            var year = 2012
            document.write("<select name='years'>");
            for (var i=1; i <=200; i++)
            {
                year++;
                document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
            }
            document.write("</select>");
            // end JS code hide -->
        </script>
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/ZHdqK/